# Get-DscConfiguration : The target namespace does not exist. DSC Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, dsc

I was testing out DSC with linux,

Here are the details of the linux server i am using

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-CimInstance -CimSession $Session -namespace root/omi -ClassName omi_identify

```
InstanceID             : 2FDB5542-5896-45D5-9BE9-DC04430AAABE
SystemName             : CENTOSTESTDSC
ProductName            : OMI
ProductVendor          : Microsoft
ProductVersionMajor    : 1
ProductVersionMinor    : 0
ProductVersionRevision : 8
ProductVersionString   : 1.0.8
Platform               : LINUX_X86_64_GNU
OperatingSystem        : LINUX
Architecture           : X86_64
Compiler               : GNU
ConfigPrefix           : GNU
ConfigLibDir           : /opt/omi-1.0.8/lib
ConfigBinDir           : /opt/omi-1.0.8/bin
ConfigIncludeDir       : /opt/omi-1.0.8/include
ConfigDataDir          : /opt/omi-1.0.8/share
ConfigLocalStateDir    : /opt/omi-1.0.8/var
ConfigSysConfDir       : /opt/omi-1.0.8/etc
ConfigProviderDir      : /opt/omi-1.0.8/etc
ConfigLogFile          : /opt/omi-1.0.8/var/log/omiserver.log
ConfigPIDFile          : /opt/omi-1.0.8/var/run/omiserver.pid
ConfigRegisterDir      : /opt/omi-1.0.8/etc/omiregister
ConfigSchemaDir        : /opt/omi-1.0.8/share/omischema
ConfigNameSpaces       : {root-check, interop, root-omi, root-cimv2}
PSComputerName         : 123.112.123.156
```

When i try to invoke a DSC configuration against the Linux VM i get an error as below.

[image]

I am using the latest PSDSC tar file from below location

```
wget https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerShell-DSC-for-Linux/releases/download/V1.1.0-466/PSDSC.tar.gz
```

Can some one help please.

Comment: `wget` just downloads the file. Did you actually extract the archive and do something with it (install it)?

Comment: yes followed this blog post http://blogs.technet.com/b/privatecloud/archive/2014/05/19/powershell-dsc-for-linux-step-by-step.aspx and completed the remaining steps

Comment: okay I got nothing then, I haven't used DSC for Linux yet :-/

Comment: ok @briantist, no probs.thanks for your help.